# It is possible to let every user on Ubuntu build their own vim?

Tags: vim, compiling

For example, user Joe builds his vim with python3 support, while user Claire builds her vim with python2 support and ruby?

User Joe can't use vim from Claire and Claire can't use vim from Joe.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the [build instructions from vim](https://www.vim.org/git.php) and put this together:

```
apt install -y git build-essential libncurses5-dev
useradd -m vimuser1
su - vimuser1
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
cd vim
./configure --prefix /home/vimuser1/newvim ${ANY_OTHER_CONFIG_OPTIONS}
make
make install
export PATH=/home/vimuser1/newvim/bin:$PATH
```

Fill in `${ANY_OTHER_CONFIG_OPTIONS}` with any other `configure` options you wanted to compile vim with.  This gave me a freshly compiled vim, only accessible by the vimuser1 user.

```
which vim
/home/vimuser1/newvim/bin/vim
```

Rinse and repeat for any number of users.